# "unpack" as "analyze" rather than "remove from container"

Tags: etymology

The older dictionaries I have include "remove from a container" as the only meaning of unpack. More recent dictionaries list "to analyze the nature of by examining in detail : " or "analyze (something) into its component elements. " as a tertiary meaning.

When did unpack start to be used to mean analyze?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but "parsing" and "unpacking" are very strongly linked in computer science, and your tertiary definition(s) are practical definitions of "to parse".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is 1596. That is the first example in the OED of a figurative meaning of 'unpack' - see below.

The OED does include a specific meaning of 'unpack' as relates to computing. Its first reference is 1954.

**OED meaning 2a. (part-of)**
fig.
1596   T. Nashe Haue with you to Saffron-Walden sig. K4,   The strange vntraffiqu't phrases, by him new vented and vnpackt.

**OED meaning 5.**

5. Computing. To convert (an item of stored data) into two or more separate items; to retrieve data from (a record). Cf. pack v.1 4d.

1954   Computers & Automation Dec. 22/2   Unpack, to separate packed items of information each into a separate machine word.

Comment: _vntraffiqu’t_ is a fantastic spelling. You know it’s English, but it still looks more like Inuktitut or something like that.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I assume it means 'untrafficked'.

Comment: Oh yes, no question about that. It’s just a fantastic way of spelling it, making it look utterly un-English, and yet recognisable. :-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'm no historian of language, but 1596 was Shakespeare's heyday. But this word seems to come from the time of  Chaucer, two hundred years earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Searching Google Ngram for “unpack the meaning” (which I assume is a typical example), the results suggest that about 1956 was a starting point, and usage really took off from about 1986.

[image]